# Waiting for a service to be deployed in K8s

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

My application contains 3 separate services. But there's an order 1,2,3 these services should start. How can I wait for 1st service to be completely up and running before starting the 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: Those services should tolerate the others not being up when they start, then you don't need to worry about the order.

Comment: That feature has yet to be implemented  as the 3 services themselves are bit complex. @jonrsharpe

Comment: I agree with @jonrsharpe, having those dependencies beats the purpose of kubernetes, and even if you can achieve this , what happens to the other services when a pod restarts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comment says, you should use timeout and retries on our code instead of hard coded dependencies.

But, to responds to you needs, you can use a initContainer on each service waiting for others.

```yaml
initContainers:
- name: wait-for-other-svc
  image: ubuntu
  args:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - >
    set -x;
    while [ $(curl -sw '%{http_code}' "service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local" -o /dev/null) -ne 200 ]; do
      sleep 1;
    done
```